# Dynamically loading CSS in angularjs (loading delay)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using two visual templates for a particular site, whose css conflicts quite a bit, so rather than doing a painful edit, I figured dynamic loading would do the trick.

So I use this in my `<head>`

```
<!-- css is loaded dynamically through angular -->
<link ng-repeat="item in css.files" ng-href="{{item}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And set `$rootScope.css.files` inside my `.config()` of my module.

The CSS loads fine, however there is a noticeable delay between loading the page content, and loading the CSS. Basically the unstyled html displays for a moment until the CSS files have completely loaded.

Is there any way to stop the page showing before the CSS has loaded? Is there any event for load completion of an `ng-href` item?

Comment: Using `ng-cloak` on your body element might be an option here. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak.

Comment: I have looked at ng-cloak and no it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will be to just use plain old css.

In the header of your page add this:

```
<style>
  html, body {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Then in the last css to load, undo the display none:

```
  html, body {
    display: block;
  }
```

The latter will override the previous, and your page will appear with all of your dynamic css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're revealing the content before the CSS files have downloaded. I don't know offhand if the `HTMLLinkElement` object has an event for when it's loaded, but basically you need to wait for your CSS to download before revealing the content. Using `ng-cloak` here won't help because `ng-cloak` hides the content while *angular* is loading, not while *other files* are loading.

Comment: Yeah, this is just a rehash of the question. Any attempt at an answer?

Comment: This is not just a rehash of the question--I recapped the problem, and then said that `ng-cloak` won't work and that the answer is to see if `HTMLLinkElement` has an event on load. In any case, it seems Jonathan.Gawrych answered with a better idea anyway.