# Avoid showing content before stylesheet is loaded with ng-href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to use ng-href to load different Themes.

The problem is that the unstyled content is shown before the stylesheet is applyed.

I made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TqJsxQjWoQbNePAU745k?p=preview) if you compare the last 3 Versions, I just changed Line 8

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link ng-href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link ng-href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/{{styleVersion}}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If I use `ng-href` instead of `href` you can see the unstyled HTML for a second what I need to avoid.

So my Question is if it is possible wait till the stylesheet is loaded or is there a better solution for this problem then `ng-href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hfl5Oe?p=preview) based on feedback I found on [Dynamically loading CSS in angularjs (loading delay)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296407/dynamically-loading-css-in-angularjs-loading-delay)

Basically it does 3 things:

1. Load a start.css file with:

   ```
   html, body{
       display: none
   }
   ```
2. Load your ng-href css
3. Load an end.css file that sets the style of the body back to `display: block`

It's a hack, but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I think loading `end.css` with a normal `href` doesn't seem to work because its loaded faster than the `ng-href`. I tryed it with `ng-href` that seems to work. And also I can think of putting the code from `end.css` at the end of my theme css. Modified [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hRszhSdVPiPQGhn3QIdl?p=preview)